# Unable to suppress x-axis label in a plotly violin plot

Tags: r, plotly, axis-labels, r-plotly

I just installed the latest `plotly` `R` `package` (`devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")`).

I'm trying to generate a violin plot for a single variable and I would like to suppress the x-axis label.

I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")
plot_ly(y =~ df$total_bill,type = 'violin',
        box = list(visible = T),
        meanline = list(visible = T)) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""),yaxis = list(title = "Total Bill",zeroline = F))
```

But I'm getting "trace 0" as the x-axis label:
[image]

I tried playing around with the `x0` parameter but couldn't get a violin with no x-axis label.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you install plotly with devtools? Cause my plotly version doesn't include `violin`-plots. I have version 4.7.1.

Comment: try this: `layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks @MLavoie. That worked!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `ggplot2` + `ggplotly`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
librart(ggplot2)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")

# Generate a ggplot with a violin plot and a boxplot
vioplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y=total_bill)) + 
   geom_violin(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) + 
   geom_boxplot(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) + 
   xlab("") + ylab("Total bill")

# Render the ggplot as a plotly object using ggplotly()
ggplotly(vioplot)
```

Here is the resulting plotly[image]

P.S. I wan't able to reproduce your plot using `plot_ly()`. I Got an error "Error: Trace type must be one of the following:...". Anyway I'm not a big fan of the `plot_ly()` way. I always go first through a ggplot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error that you're getting is probably because you're not using the latest plotly version. As to using ggplot over plotly, I personally disagree. plotly automates setting dimensions and labels font size which ggplot makes you try out till you get sick of it.